# Video streaming on Android app with motion on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, android, mplayer

I am trying to view a live streaming by motion on my Raspberry Pi through an Android App written with Android Studio...I have compound this code using mplayer:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
private SurfaceView vidSurface;
String vidAddress = "http://www.example.com/";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(vidAddress);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
}
```

But it does not work. If I put an url of a streaming video (not live) for example: www.something.com/vid.mp4 it works. (Yes, I have added internet permission on manifest). Anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your motion config?

Comment: @Fildor Here you are: http://pastebin.com/wSFSQX8G

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are inserting a web address without a file at the end - that might be your cause. Motion uses the file stream.mjpg, so the local address by default would be http://hostip:8081/stream.mjpg

Source: http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#Webcam_Server